# solving the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-y)^2$ given $y(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am given to solve the Cauchy problem :

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-y)^2
$$ given $y(0)=0$.

I am not able to arrive at any standard solvable form of ODE.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Substitute $$x-y=u$$ then we get $$y'=1-u'=u^2$$
Can you finish?

Comment: million thanks.

Comment: I don't Need a Million, nice that i could help you!